# Nodejs HTML Selection List

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to nodejs and mysql.  I am having issues generating a list with data stored in MySQL.  Everything else works fine, I would like to have the selection drop down of "Country" to be generated from whatever is in the MYSQL "test" table.  This is as far as I got, in the future I would look to be adding more selection list with more data generated from MYSQL.  I'm not sure what code to write to generate the loop to read the data from http://localhost:7002/getJson, or of this is even the way to go about it.  Any assistance will be appreciated!  Thank you

[image]
routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
 });

 app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login.ejs', {message:req.flash('loginMessage')});
 });

 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
 }),
  function(req, res){
   if(req.body.remember){
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
   }else{
    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
   }
   res.redirect('/');
  });

 app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
  res.render('signup.ejs', {message: req.flash('signupMessage')});
 });

 app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
 }));

 app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  res.render('profile.ejs', {
   user:req.user
  });
 });

 app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
 })

 //-SQL QUERY
 var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

 var app = express();

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "password",
    database: 'test'
 });

 connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

 // all environments
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);


 app.get('/getJson',function(req,res){
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM Country', function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err); 
        res.json({"error":true});
    }
    else { 
        console.log(result); 
        res.json(result); 
    }
        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));

    });

 } );

 http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });
 };

 //-SQL QUERY END



function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
 if(req.isAuthenticated())
  return next();

 res.redirect('/');
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({
 secret: 'justasecret',
 resave:true,
 saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());


require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

app.listen(port);
console.log("Port: " + port);
```

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);

module.exports = function(passport) {
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ", [id],
   function(err, rows){
    done(err, rows[0]);
   });
 });

 passport.use(
  'local-signup',
  new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField : 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done){
    var fruit= req.body.fruit;
    var PhoneNumber= req.body.PhoneNumber;
    var Country= req.body.Country;
    var newUserMysql = {
          username: username,
          password: password,
          fruit: fruit,
          PhoneNumber: PhoneNumber,
          Country: Country,
         };

         var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fruit, PhoneNumber, Country) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

         connection.query(insertQuery, [newUserMysql.username,newUserMysql.password, newUserMysql.closureplan,newUserMysql.UIR,newUserMysql.CSJ],
          function(err, rows){
           newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

           return done(null, newUserMysql);
          });

  })
 );

 passport.use(
  'local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField : 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done){
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? ", [username],
   function(err, rows){
    if(err)
     return done(err);
    if(!rows.length){
     return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No User Found'));
    }
    if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
     return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong Password'));

    return done(null, rows[0]);
   });
  })
 );
};
```

signup.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Login Register</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style>
  html{
   padding:50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   <h2>Register</h2>

   <% if(message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div> 
   <% } %>

   <form action="/signup" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Username</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Password</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Fruit:</label>
            <select name="fruit" type="form" class="form-control">
              <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
              <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
              <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
            </select><br />


    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone Number#</label>
        <input name="PhoneNumber" type="textbox" class="form-control" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Country</label>
        <select name="Country" type="form" class="custom-select">

       </select><br>
    </div>





    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succcess btn-lg">Register</button>
   </form>

   <hr>

   <p>Need an account <a href="/signup">Register</a></p>
   <p>Go Back <a href="/">Home</a>.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

database.js

```
module.exports = {
 'connection':{
  'host':'localhost',
  'user':'root',
  'password':'password'
 },
 'database':'signup',
 'user_table':'information',

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your front end code you GET `/getJSON` which returns a `JSON` object. Then you need to append the elements to your `<select>` tag as `<option>`s

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
    let select = document.getElementById("test");
    json.forEach(e=>{
      var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
      opt1.text = e.title;
      opt1.value = e.id;
      select.add(opt1);
    });
    
  })
```

```html
<select id="test">
</select>
```

Comment: generally people serve their javascript in a /public/scripts/ folder and then in the `html` they use a `<script src="/public/scripts/index.js">/<script>` type of deal

Comment: for testing you can also just put it right in the ejs/html inside a `<script></script>` tag

Comment: When I am trying to go to I get http://localhost:7002/getJsonError [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.  Is that correct?  
Is let select = document.getElementById("test"); is that the table name?
and opt1.text = e.title;  opt1.value = e.id; are the columns?

Comment: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` --- this is an error in your `/getJson` route possibly

Comment: Remove the lines `console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));` from your `/getJson`

Comment: document.getElementById("test") is the `<select id="test">...` element

Comment: I was able to run your test code and it generated a list.  When I ran my JSON list that generated to http://localhost:7002/getJson, it did not generate a list.  In the termianl however, it did say RowData Packet { id: 1, title: 'Test1'},....and so on.

Comment: your row data is likely different than that test url I gave you

Comment: I had to format the results using console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); in route.js.
The terminal now returns [{"id:1, "title": "Test1"},...and so on.  Does it have something to do with the json.forEach loop..opt1.text =e.title; opt1.value=e.id;?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will mark this as resolved.  I opened a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885219/passing-mysql-data-to-html-select-list