# Passing MySQL data to HTML Select List

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I need some assistance in passing the MYSQL query results to an HTML select list.  I was able to pass some data from a JSON list from here - http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos, but am unable to pass my own data that is sent to localhost:7002/getJson.  Is it a formatting thing, please take a look at my code and data and see what can be changed.  Thanks!

route.js

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
 });

 app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login.ejs', {message:req.flash('loginMessage')});
 });

 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
 }),
  function(req, res){
   if(req.body.remember){
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
   }else{
    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
   }
   res.redirect('/');
  });

 app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
  res.render('signup.ejs', {message: req.flash('signupMessage')});
 });

 app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
 }));

 app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  res.render('profile.ejs', {
   user:req.user
  });
 });

 app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
 })

 //-SQL QUERY
 var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

 var app = express();

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "password",
    database: 'testdb'
 });

 connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

 // all environments
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);


 app.get('/getJson',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM testtable', function(err, result, fields){
       if(err) {
           console.log(err); 
           res.json({"error":true});
       }
       else { 
        //    console.log(result); 
           console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
           res.json(result); 

       }


       });

    } );

 http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });
 };

 //-SQL QUERY END


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
 if(req.isAuthenticated())
  return next();

 res.redirect('/');
}
```

signup.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Login Register</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style>
  html{
   padding:50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   <h2>Register</h2>

   <% if(message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div> 
   <% } %>

   <form action="/signup" method="post">
    <script>
        fetch('http://localhost:7002/getJson')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json);
          let select = document.getElementById("test");
          json.forEach(e=>{
            var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
            opt1.text = e.title;
            opt1.value = e.id;
            select.add(opt1);
          });

        })</script>

    <script>
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
        //   console.log(json);
          let select = document.getElementById("hi");
          json.forEach(e=>{
            var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
            opt1.text = e.title;
            // opt1.value = e.id;
            select.add(opt1);
          });

        })</script>   

    <div class="form-group">
       <select id="test">
       </select><br>
       <select id="hi">
      </select><br>

    </div>




    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succcess btn-lg">Register</button>
   </form>

   <hr>

   <p>Need an account <a href="/signup">Register</a></p>
   <p>Go Back <a href="/">Home</a>.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

from: http://localhost:7002/getJson
[image]

from: http://localhost:8080/signup
[image]

from console

[image]

Comment: Did you check the browser's javascript console? Are you serving the HTML page from http://localhost:7002?

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:7002/getJson' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
and 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

this is the error that it showed in the console

Comment: in your `<script>` fetch statement you need to change `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos` to `http://localhost:7002/getJson` and I would un-comment `// opt1.value = e.id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is being blocked by CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) policies, because your hosts are different (localhost:8080 and localhost:7002) and there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the responde from the express server.

You can add support to CORS from the origin site (localhost:8000) adding some  HTTP headers to the express server:

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:8000"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```